# Calling print in the middle of a python list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

So I'm trying to pull off a trick I actually first heard about on this site.

```
[i for i in range(0, 10) if True or print(i)]
```

The idea being that you can call an arbitrary function at every step of a listcomp by sticking it inside an "if" statement that will always return True. But that code gives a syntax error.

If I wrap the function I want to call like this, though:

```
def f(i):
    print i

[i for i in range(0, 10) if True or f(i)]
```

it produces the desired output. So I was wondering what the difference is, in Python's mind, between the two, because I can't tell what it could be -- both functions return "None", right?

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function`; but why do you need to have the side effect at all?

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions in place of a for-loop if you don't actually need the list it produces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot mix statements (like `print` in Python 2) with a list comprehension.

However, you *can* make `print()` a function by adding:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top of your file. This turns `print()` into a function for the *whole* module.

However, you are using the statement `True or something` and that will never evaluate 'something' because Python boolean expressions short-circuit. You want to turn that around:

```
if print(something) or True
```

There is no point in evaluating the right-hand side of a `or` expression if the left-hand side already evaluated to `True`; nothing the right-hand side can come up with will make the whole expression `False`, ever.

You really want to *avoid* such side effects in a list comprehension though. Use a proper loop and keep such surprises out of your code, using `if something or True` is really a hack that will confuse future maintainers of your code (including you).

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I didn't know that print() wasn't a function. And you're right about the short-circuiting thing: the code I provided actually doesn't produce the correct output -- what I was thinking of was "not f(i)".

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2.x, print is not a function.  It became a function in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a statement in py2x not expression so it can't be used where an expression is expected.

You need to import `print_function` from `__future__` in order to make it work.

```
In [105]: from __future__ import print_function

In [107]: [i for i in range(0, 10) if print(i) or True]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Out[107]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Note that as `print()` returns `None` so in your `or` condition it must be placed first or use an `and` condition : `if  True and not print(i)`

Comment: That is the return value of the list comprehension; `print()` is *not called*.

Comment: `True and print(i)` won't do what you want; it'd evaluate to `False` instead and nothing would be added to the resulting list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ah! yes, forgot to add a `not` before it.

Comment: The `or True` version is more generic as it doesn't matter what the first expression returns. If you swap `print()` with something that could return anything, a mix of true and false values, `or True` makes sure it's always going to be `True`.

Comment: Not that the OP really should use this *at all*.